# Natural cubic splines with stationary time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, stationarity, splines

I have two periodic but stationary time series (at least mean-stationary, variances may be a bit heteroscedastic but only slightly) and I would like to see how do they correlate. I know that I can possibly use standard linear correlation in this case, but it seems that there is a bit of non-linear relationship between the two series. Therefore I would also like to build a natural cubic splines model and extract its $R^2$ to see how much better a non-linear fit is than a liner one.

So I wonder if the strategy I outlined above is reasonable or not?